# Using GoogleTestRunner in our TFS Build

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild, googletest

We are using the Google Test framework (version 1.7) for unit tests in C++ project (with Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012). By using [GoogleTestRunner for VS2012](https://github.com/markusl/GoogleTestRunner/tree/master/Latest_VS2012_package) I am able to discover the tests written in Google Test within Visual Studio and run them. So far so good :)

Now I would like to run the tests with my CI build I have set up on our TFS. Therefore I have installed the GoogleTestRunner on my build server for the user that runs our build. If I run the build (and tests) on the build server directly in Visual Studio it works - but when the build is triggered by the TFS build definition I displays the following message in the log:

> No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors,
>   platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Any suggestion what I am missing?
Is this working for anybody at all?

Your help is highly appreciated!

Christoph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to sort it out myself :)

There is a guide showing how to get it running for NUnit. Just follow that guide and adopt it to the GoogleTestRunner:
http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2012/10/tfs-2012-build-configure-nunit-to-run.html

I extracted the DLLs from the GoogleTestRunner.vsix file with 7zip (I assume any other Zip program would work as well). I checked in all DLLs I found there (as described in the mentioned guide) - don't know if really all DLLs are needed.